# Acquiring BIOS string information

Tags: x86, intel, bios, uefi, amd-processor

At boot time (using F2, F9 etc) in the BIOS setup screen:

- Does the BIOS use [*CPUID*](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid) to retrieve the information about the machine?
- If the BIOS does use *CPUID* to retrieve the information what kind of parameters would I have to pass to *CPUID* to get similar information?
- If the BIOS doesn't use *CPUID* to acquire the data then what method does it use?

Comment: http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm

Comment: It's still not particularly clear exactly what information you want to get out of CPUID.  IDK what your bios prints when you press F2; I think mine goes into its setup menu where it shows fan speeds and voltages and all kinds of mobo stuff that the CPU itself doesn't know about (accessible via I/O, not `cpuid`).

Comment: And BTW, no, `cpuid` doesn't know how much RAM you have.  Only how cache, because cache is built-in to the CPU.  Everything you can read with CPUID is set at the factory, before the CPU is put into a motherboard with RAM.  (This isn't strictly true; microcode updates can change CPUID, and virtualization can hook it.  But for settings other than the CPU itself, you need to read MSRs or do I/O to other devices.)

Comment: bios string information such as cpu and frequency and how much  ram you have and ...

Comment: @PeterCordes can you recommend a  good books about the subject of bios

Comment: I have no idea, it's not a subject I'm particularly interested in.  You might want to look at the source code for `dmidecode` to see how it queries system info.

Comment: You will want to review the [SMBIOS documentation](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf). If supported on  your system you can search for the string *_SM_* in memory starting at 0xF0000 (through 0xFFFFF). If found you need to unpack the data. Starting at page 21 in that document you can find more about this and the structure. If using EFI the base address of the table can be queried.